# VBA Workbook Savechanges = False still saving and closing workbook when running Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main workbook that extracts data from other workbook sheets, then closes the modified workbook suppressing the save option.

> other_wb.Close Savechanges = False

However when running the macro or stepping through this function call in DEBUG mode it still saves the file. Is there an alternative way to close without saving? Is there any explanation for this behavior?

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: please provide more of the code. specifically how you set `other_wb`

Comment: @GSerg explained it well actually, I provided all the info I need

Comment: Please don't use the [macros] tag for Excel/VBA questions. The tag info for it says, `*Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages. Use the respective tags instead.*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Savechanges` is an undefined variable. It is therefore `Empty`; `Empty` is falsy, so the expression `Savechanges = False` evaluates to `True`, so the call becomes `other_wb.Close True`, which saves the file.

You are missing the colon:

```
other_wb.Close Savechanges:= False
```

Put `Option Explicit` on top of all your code modules to never have to deal with this kind of issues.

Comment: Are you saying Savechanges = False evaluates Nothing = False -> True?

Comment: No, I'm saying it evaluates `Empty = False` => `True`.

Comment: @GSerg Well spotted!!

Answer (score 0):

Use other_wb.AutoSaveOn = False before you do your changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There does seem to be a bug in the version of Excel that I have -- Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64-bit

In particular, the SaveChanges parameter for workbook close is not recognized. For example:

```
DataWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
```

Not only does that not work when executed -- the workbook is closed without being saved -- the code editor/parser does not even recognize the SaveChanges parameter. The proof of that is that it does not change "savechanges" to "SaveChanges" in the above statement.

So, in the absence of a workaround, which I'd love to see, I have switched to the following:

```
DataWorkbook.Save
DataWorkbook.Close
```

The only potential drawback is that if there were no changes, then I believe that the Save function still saves. So if there are resource issues with an unnecessary save, or having a precisely correct timestamp on the saved file is important, that may be a problem. Otherwise, it seems fine.