# HOW DO I REMOVE LINK TO IMAGE

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code works good at inserting images and adjusting. The problem I have is when you open in another pc the images are missing and a it shows link missing. Can anyone help me with this fix?

```
Sub ChangeImage()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            Dim img As Object
            Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1), LinkToFile = False)
             LinkToFile = False
             SaveWithDocument = True
            'Scale image size
            'img.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth .75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            'img.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight .75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

            'Position Image
            img.Left = 568
            img.Top = 63

            'Set image sizes in points (71 point per inch)
            img.Width = 155
            img.Height = 91
        Else
            MsgBox ("You Forgot Your Image.")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Those `LinkToFile` and `SaveWithDocument`, are they meant to be properties of an object? (Because I guess they are currently undeclared variables. Put `option explicit` at the top.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Workbook Savechanges = False still saving and closing workbook when running Macro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38509557/11683)

Comment: @YowE3K They need to replace `LinkToFile = False` with `LinkToFile := False`, which is why it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Gserg - Ahhh - I had noticed the weirdness of `LinkToFile = False`, but the MSDN page I found about `Pictures.Insert` said that the second parameter (of only two parameters) was the `Converter` parameter which took an object, so I was thinking the reference to `LinkToFile` was just plain wrong.

Comment: @gserg - It looks like `LinkToFile` is a parameter to the `Shapes.AddPicture` method, but not to the `Pictures.Insert` method.

Comment: `MsgBox ("You Forgot Your Image.")` - these superfluous parentheses will eventually bite you in the rear end. [See why on Documentation.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201611081923154601046).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Sub ChangeImage()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                                                      LinkToFile:=False, _
                                                      SaveWithDocument:=True, _
                                                      Left:=568, _
                                                      Top:=63, _
                                                      Width:=155, _
                                                      Height:=91

        Else
            MsgBox ("You Forgot Your Image.")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

(And, as GSerg suggested in a comment, include `Option Explicit` at the start of all your code modules to ensure that your variables are correctly defined.)