# VBA : Creating Read-Only / Password-Protected Word document when opened (not Edited)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How would I make a vba program which enables readonly function but also needs a password to open the document up when launched and im not refering to the password I would need to edit the document if in a read only state.

Everytime I enable the Readonly function using code to the document it wipes the password off the document and only has the readonly but editable.

```
wd.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\" & URNa & " - " & URNb & ".docx", Password:=CombinePass, 
ReadOnly=True
```

Comment: There is no argument called `ReadOnly`. If this is your exact code, then what it actually does is, [most likely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38509588/11683), `wd.SaveAs Filename:="...", Password:=CombinePass, AddToRecentFiles:=False`.

Comment: you could add an `input box` and ask for a "password" if that doenst match your stored password then exit.. just a thought.

Comment: @gserg ReadOnlyRecommended := True

Comment: @alowflyingpig the password section works fine if I remove the read only function

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you want. Are you saying that 1) the document may only be opened by someone with the password and that 2) once the document is open, no content should be editable?

Comment: @CindyMeister yes that is correct, for some reason the docment wipes the password if readonly is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word has two kinds of password protection:

- at the **file** level
- at the **document** level

The `SaveAs` method works at the file level. When the password is specified, that prevents the file from opening unless the password is supplied.

The `ReadOnlyRecommended` parameter when set to `true` allows a document to be opened, but it cannot be saved *back to the same name*.

So 1) `ReadOnlyRecommended` doesn't do what most people expect and 2) the two parameters essentially contradict one another - both cannot be used together.

In order to allow the file to open, but ensure the file content cannot be edited, it's necessary to protect that content at the document level:

```
wd.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, Type.Missing, "test", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Note that this kind of protection also allows editing of certain parts of the document, when those parts are specified before protection is applied.

Comment: Perfect, yes this makes sense

Comment: @DrG Glad it helps :-) A reminder: on Stack Overflow the accepted way to "thank" is to mark the contribution which answers the question as "the" answer, by clicking the checkmark at the left. This also lets others know the question is no longer open, and signals people looking for help with a similar issue that the question received an answer :-) Hope the project is now working well.